# Appirater doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, appirater

I'm trying to implement Appirater in my app. I've followed the instructions in the read me, and the app runs fine in Xcode. But no message is shown, no matter how many times i try to run it. I have edited the #defines, so the problem shouldn't be there. When APPIRATER_DEBUG is enabled, it also doesn't show anything. I've tried cleaning the project, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: You might want to post some code!

Comment: Have you called `  [Appirater appLaunched:YES];` ?

Comment: I call [Appirater appLaunched:YES]; in -(void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application, and [Appirater appEnteredForeground:YES]; in -(void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application. I've also changed APPIRATER_APP_ID to my application's ID. When APPIRATER_DEBUG is enabled, it displays the use count in the console, but a UIAlertView doesn't pop up as it says in should in the description. It also doesn't pop up when use count is greater than APPIRATER_USES_UNTIL_PROMPT.

Comment: @Yorxxx Your comment fixed it in my case, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You imported Appirater in AppDelegate.ma It should now open the pop-up to the launch of the app

## import "AppDelegate.h"

## import "Appirater.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
  [Appirater appLaunched];

  return YES;
  }